# python logging use same handlers for multiple loggers on different files

Tags: python, python-logging

I have an old project where i used only print statements and i want to start using the logging module.
This is the project's structure:

- MAIN.py - main executable
- TASKS.py
- LOG_SERIAL.py

when execute, i get user input and then i go to TASK.py and LOG_SERIAL.py (threads).

1. For MAIN.py\TASKS.py I plan to use two loggers and handlers(stream, file) so they will contain the same data and change their level names

Example:
stream \ file

```
DATE - NAME - SYSTEM - "....."
DATE - NAME - SYSTEM - "....."
DATE - NAME - TASKS - "...."
DATE - NAME - TASKS - "...."
```

2. use one more logger for LOG_SERIAL.py that will log to a different file

This is what i did so far:

1. I created on main.py the following method:

```
# main.py
import TASKS
def get_logger():
    FORMAT = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-[%(levelname)s]-%(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('console.log', mode='w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    logging.addLevelName(logging.DEBUG, 'SYSTEM')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

and then I used it on MAIN.py:

```
logger = get_logger()
logger.debug("...")
```

2. I created on TASKS.py the same method but changed the mode for the file handler, level name and value

```
# tasks.py
def get_logger():
    FORMAT = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-[%(levelname)s]-%(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('console.log', mode='a+')
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, 'TASKS')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

and then i call:

```
logger = get_logger()
logger.info("...")
```

this is what i get for both handlers:

```
2021-06-14 19:35:42,253-__main__-[SYSTEM]-"..."
2021-06-14 19:35:49,576-clients-[TASKS]-"...."
```

I believe it can be done better without the boilerplate code on tasks.py.

1. what is the recommended way for my scenario? two loggers which use the same handlers on different files
2. how can i get the get the module name instead of "__ main __ "?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing many things, so here is a recap :

- the name of the logger, which your FORMAT specified to include in the log output (`%(name)s`), is not the best option here, you could use others (cf [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)) :

  - `%(filename)s` will give you `main.py`
  - `%(module)s` will give you `main`
- `__name__` is the module name, not the file name (cf [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), search for `__file__`)

  - when you import a module, for example by `import os.path`, then `os.path` will be the value for `__name__` in this module
  - but for the special case of the first module, which is not explicitely imported (you just gave it to Python to run), then its `__name__` will be  `__main__` (cf [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html))
- `__file__` is the absolute path to the file, for example `C:/PycharmProjects/stack_overflow/q67975119/main.py` in my case
- you are aliasing a log level as "SYSTEM", so that it gets written in the output. It is not recommended to use logging levels for other things than log (severity) levels.
- your function `get_logger` does the configuration then returning an instace. But the logging configuration is **global** so that calling it a second time will have nasty side-effects (specially `addHandler`), so it is not recommended to mix the actual **setup** of the logging infrastructure with getting an instance.

And here are the solutions to your problems :

- to display `SYSTEM` as name for the logger, you can :

  - either put it as a constant in your `FORMAT` : `'%(asctime)s-SYSTEM-[%(levelname)s]-%(message)s'`
  - or name your logger `SYSTEM`, so replace your logger creation by `logger = logging.getLogger("SYSTEM")`
- to indicate that a log line is about the system, either use it as logger name (cf above), or use a [logger adapter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information).
- extract the logging setup from your `get_logger` function into another one, that only gets called once, when the program starts (preferably in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block).

My recommendation is not use `__file__` nor `__name__` for your loggers names, just give them names like `"main"` and `"tasks"`. If you don't intend to rename your source files, it is a simpler and more flexible solution.

Tip : change your `FileHandler` mode to `w+` or `a` so that each new time your program run, the logs are appended to those of the previous run, instead of overwriting (losing) them.

Here is a complete example :

```py
# main.py
import logging

from q67975119 import serial, tasks


def setup_main_logging():
    FORMAT = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('console.log', mode='w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    system_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    system_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    system_logger.addHandler(file_handler)


system_logger = logging.getLogger("SYSTEM")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_main_logging()  # before using the logger for the first time !
    tasks.setup_tasks_logging()  # before using the logger for the first time !
    system_logger.debug(f"__file__={__file__!r}")
    system_logger.debug(f"__name__={__name__!r}")
    tasks.do_task()
    serial.do_serial()
```

```py
# serial.py
def do_serial():
    import main  # to prevent circular imports
    system_logger = main.system_logger
    system_logger.info(f"__file__={__file__!r}")
    system_logger.info(f"__name__={__name__!r}")
```

```
# tasks.py
import logging


def setup_tasks_logging():
    FORMAT = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('console.log', mode='a+')
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMAT)
    tasks_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    tasks_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    tasks_logger.addHandler(file_handler)


tasks_logger = logging.getLogger("TASKS")


def do_task():
    tasks_logger.info(f"__file__={__file__!r}")
    tasks_logger.info(f"__name__={__name__!r}")
```

When run I get the same thing in stdout and the file :

```
2021-06-17 11:50:19,661 - SYSTEM - [DEBUG] - __file__='C:/Users/PycharmProjects/stack_overflow/q67975119/main.py'
2021-06-17 11:50:19,661 - SYSTEM - [DEBUG] - __name__='__main__'
2021-06-17 11:50:19,661 - TASKS - [INFO] - __file__='C:/Users/PycharmProjects/stack_overflow/q67975119/tasks.py'
2021-06-17 11:50:19,661 - TASKS - [INFO] - __name__='q67975119.tasks'
2021-06-17 11:50:19,663 - SYSTEM - [INFO] - __file__='C:/Users/PycharmProjects/stack_overflow/q67975119/serial.py'
2021-06-17 11:50:19,663 - SYSTEM - [INFO] - __name__='q67975119.serial'
```

If you want to reduce the boilerplate you can use [`logging.config`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html) which allow you to put your config in a text file or a Python dictionnary, and give it as-is to the logging library.

Example using a file :

```py
# main.py
import logging.config

from q67975119 import serial, tasks


system_logger = logging.getLogger("SYSTEM")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.config.fileConfig("logging.config")
    system_logger.debug(f"__file__={__file__!r}")
    system_logger.debug(f"__name__={__name__!r}")
    tasks.do_task()
    serial.do_serial()
```

and the `logging.config` file :

```
[loggers]
keys=root,system,tasks

[handlers]
keys=console,file

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=console,file

[logger_system]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console,file
propagate=0
qualname=SYSTEM

[logger_tasks]
level=INFO
handlers=console,file
propagate=0
qualname=TASKS

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file]
class=FileHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=formatter
args=('console.log', 'w+')

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

It produces the exact same outputs (stdout and file) than specifying everything by code.